# No funciona este alias, aparentemente bien escrito

Tags: linux, bash

He añadido este alias a `jo/.bashrc`:

```
alias lm='cd /home/jose/Escritorio/GRADO\ SUPERIOR/.lmfinal/'
```

Sin embargo, cada vez que escribo `lm` no me lo pilla.

Comment: Has cargado el `.bashrc` una vez modificado mediante `source .bashrc` o has reinicado el shell? el `bash` te da algún error?

Comment: no entiendo lo de que si  **he cargado el .bashrc mediante source .bashrc** ni tampoco lo de **reiniciar el shell**

Comment: de locos , ya funciona, tenia que hacer lo del source .bashrc , que maquiina, pero no se lo que hace eso. MIL GRACIAS

Comment: que va, tuve que hacer **source ~/.bashrc** para que funcionara, solo era eso, lo unico es que no se que es ese comando

Comment: Si solo editas el `.bashrc` para agregar el alias, hay que volver a cargarlo con el `source` o cerrar y volver a abrir. el `source`es un comando de `bash`que ejecuta un archivo pasado por parámetro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Bash una forma de hacer permanente un configuración particular, como en tu ejemplo un `alias`, es editar directamente el archivo `.bashrc`, que es un archivo que se invoca siempre al iniciar nuestro `shell`.

Haciendo esto, lo que hay que tener en cuenta es que se está modificando el comportamiento del próximo `bash` que invoquemos y no el del actual.

Para ver el cambio reflejado en nuestro `shell` activo hay dos formas:

1. Ejecutando directamente el comando `alias lm='cd /home/jose/Escritorio/GRADO\ SUPERIOR/.lmfinal/'` en el terminal.
2. Haciendo un "refresh" de la configuración mediante el comando interno [`source`](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html), es decir: `source .bashrc`. De manera mucho más sencilla y además más óptima al ser un estándar POSIX (gracias Ivan & fedorqui) se puede hacer uso del comando equivalente a `source` que es `.` mediante `. .bashrc`.

En todo momento puedes ver qué alias tienes definidos escribiendo `alias` en tu consola. Si quieres ver uno en concreto puedes escribir `alias lm`.

Comment: Tambien bastaria con hacer `. .bashrc` para refrescar las variables.

Comment: Muchas distribuciones cargan el .bashrc, pero otras trabajan con .bash_profile

Comment: No exactamente, la idea de `.bash_profile` es que se usa para `login shells` y `.bashrc` para `interactive non-login shells`, en la práctica se usan ambos archivos, el primero, solo cuando se hace un login y el segundo para cualquier `shell` interactivo, al menos en teoría.

Comment: Es al contrario: `.` lo define POSIX y `source` no. En Bash y otros no afecta, pero suele recomendarse usar el punto. Referencias: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58518/40596

Comment: La verdad que desconocía eso @fedorqui, gracias, lo agrego a la respuesta.